# Prevent Outlook converting shape with text into image

Tags: image, text, outlook

If you create a shape with text inside and send it, the recipient will only see an image.
In other words, he won't be able to **copy the text**... which defeats the purpose of sending text.

I found two workarounds, none really useful:
a)
Right click on the image > Grouping > Ungroup
This certainly makes the text copyable, but I need a solution where recipients can simply copy the text anyway.

b)
File > Options > Mail > Compose messages in > set to Rich Text
However this does not work for me at all...

I found several articles on the internet but none could explain more.
However I have seen someone solving it in front of my eyes before so it can definitely be done (but that person is gone now).

Using Outlook 2010

Any help is much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you send in the RTF format (I am not sure why that does not work for you), embedded OLE objects are gone - Outlook converts them to images since that is the only thing that HTML can handle.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
You were right, what I did differently was opening an email in Inbox that contained an .oft attachment and tried to send that one.
Therefore it was not a "new" email technically, making the setting in "Options > Mail > Compose new messages in this format: Rich text"  irrelevant.

I guess there is no real solution for this... (forcing RTF even on incoming HTML formats)

My workaround was to open the incoming attachment, save it as RTF + .ofl and attaching it again.
Of course it is not a solution for standard incoming mails... (that are already HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that it is simply **not possible.**

Best solution/workaround was using **RTF format**

*File > Options > Mail > Compose messages in > set to Rich Text*

Answer (score 0):

Work around is simple (although took me a while to think of it!).  Send to yourself / create an image as per your shape/text.  Add the IMAGE to the e-mail and Link this image.  This will then remain as a linkable image when sent.